# send email through cakephp shell Fatal error: Class 'CakeLog' not found

Tags: email, shell, cakephp

i am trying to send email using cakephp shell. Following is my code:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(0);
class EmailShell extends AppShell {
    public $uses = array('Email');

    public function show() {
        $Email = new CakeEmail();
        $Email->from('abc@gmail.com');
        $Email->to('xyz@gmail.com');
        $Email->subject('Forgot Password');
        $Email->send();
    }
}
?>
```

when i run this in shell i get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'CakeLog' not found in /mnt/public_html/music_directory/web/cakephp/app/Config/bootstrap.php on line 172
```

where am i getting wrong? how do i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually use the CakeLog class that early (in your own bootstrap)
you need to assert it is loaded.

You forgot the following statement prior to using the class:

```
 App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');
```

Comment: hey thanks mate! can you please also suggest how do i make this script a cron job?

Comment: thanks a lot, I ll have to ask my admin to set up a cron job :)